# Order of /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin and more in $PATH

Tags: macos, bash, path

On my Mac I used bash a lot. For my environment settings I added `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` into `$PATH` as I normally did.

While I do know what `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` are about, I am curious which should go before another, by convention? And is there a specific reason for that?

Similar is for `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` -- hopefully the answer is the same or similar.

a bit more --
Just an extension of the original question, how would you order the following in $PATH following the convention and why?

```
/bin
/sbin
/usr/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
```

Comment: See also [this related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`/usr/bin` is where binaries supplied by the OS go. `/usr/local/bin` is where user supplied binaries go. When you type the name of a command on the command line, the shell searches for said command in the paths contained in the `$PATH` environment variable *in order*. A common pattern is to have `/usr/local/bin` precede `/usr/bin` in `$PATH`. This allows you to install alternate versions of binaries and have them gracefully "override" the binaries provided by the OS. And OS updates won't clobber your user installed packages. This pattern is notably used in OSX by the popular [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) package manager tool.

For instance, at the time of this writing, OSX El Capitan supplies git version 2.5.4 (in `/usr/bin`). If you want a newer version, you can use Homebrew to install git version 2.7.0 (into `/usr/local/bin`). Since `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` in the `$PATH` environment variable, when you issue the command `git` in a shell, the newer Homebrew version will be used.

On fresh new Mac running OSX El Capitan (I happen to have one), the `/etc/paths` file contains the following:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

which produces the following `$PATH` environment variable:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

which is compatible with homebrew. I recommend sticking with this OSX default. If you really want to include `/usr/local/sbin` (listed in your question above), I would put it just before `/usr/sbin` for similar reasons to above. As for `/opt/local/bin` and `/opt/local/sbin`, I haven't personally found the need to add them to the path but it seems they might go in a similar spot as their `/usr/local` analogs, since `/opt` traditionally contains user installed binaries.

Note: The same explanation applies to `/usr/lib` vs. `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: I'm confused. When I do `cat /etc/paths` I get: `/usr/local/bin`,`/usr/bin`,etc. 
However, when I `echo $PATH` I get: `/usr/bin:/bin/:`, etc. which is a different order completely. (I should mention this is on Yosemite 10.10)

Comment: @skube Check if there is a `$PATH` environment variable override in your user's `~/.bash_profile`. If so, comment it out or delete it.

Comment: Be aware if you change the rights of the `/usr/local/bin` folder to *writeable* for the *user*, then user apps can just replace sudo with a fake sudo at `/usr/local/bin/sudo` if you have `/usr/local/bin/` higher than `/usr/bin/` in `PATH`.

Comment: @Binarian A user app can simply add an alias to your .bashrc to achieve the same effect. No, putting /usr/loca/bin after /usr/bin cannot protect you from running a malicious sudo.

Comment: @YongweiWu Thanks for the input. Yes you are right. You described another attack vector, which can make the protection irrelevant if not protected against changing configuration files. What I said is still correct, even if it only accounts for one attack vector.