# brew-installed Python not overriding system python

Tags: python, macos, path, homebrew

I just used brew to install Python 3 on OS X.  The `python3` command now starts the interpreter using brew Python 3.6, but `python` still opens the interpreter with the default system Python 2.7.

My understanding was that, by default, brew Python should now override system Python.  (I.e., see [Order of /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin and more in $PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984870/order-of-usr-bin-and-usr-local-bin-and-more-in-path)). In my PATH, /usr/local/bin comes before /usr/bin, so it shouldn't be a PATH issue.  I have tried restarting Terminal, with no effect.

Here is my full PATH in case that is relevant.

```
/Users/**/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin:/Users/**/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/bin:/Users/**/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin:/Users/**/.rvm/bin:/Users/**/.rvm/bin:/Users/**/Python/PmagPy/programs/conversion_scripts2/:/Users/**/Python/PmagPy/programs/conversion_scripts/:/Users/**/Python/PmagPy/programs:/usr/local/heroku/bin:./bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Why isn't brew Python taking precedence?  And how can I fix (or troubleshoot) this?  If I can't find another option, I can create an alias, but I prefer to understand what's happening and get to the root of the problem.

Update:

I checked out the "possible duplicate" question, but my issue doesn't appear to be a linking problem:

```
 ~ brew link --overwrite --dry-run python
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4
To relink: brew unlink python && brew link python
 ~
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link home brew python version and set it as default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340871/how-to-link-home-brew-python-version-and-set-it-as-default)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**TL;DR** Add the following to your `.bash_profile` (or equivalent):

`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"`

**Explanation**

It seems python via homebrew is now handled differently (see https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python).

> - `python3` points to Homebrew’s Python 3.x (if installed)
> - `python2` points to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x (if installed)
> - `python` points to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x (if installed) otherwise the macOS system Python. Check out `brew info python` if you wish to add
>     Homebrew’s 3.x python to your PATH.

Checking out `brew info python` hints at what you need to do:

> Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
>   `python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been
>   installed into /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin

The hint being that you therefore have to add `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin` before `/usr/bin` in your path (not `/usr/local/bin` as stated in some sources e.g. https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/)

See also https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/15746

Comment: After spending an hour messing with it, this finally did it! Thank you!!!

Comment: I know you're not supposed to overwrite the system installation of python at `/usr/bin/python` on macOS, so why is this different? I know that it's not actually overwriting, but I would think that this would have the same effect of making programs that rely on `python` use `python3` when they are trying to use python 2.

Comment: You're right, but unless the script is compatible with both python 2.x and 3.x, I believe it is good practice to explicitly state the version if it will be run by the system in some manner e.g. with `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305076/1265167

Comment: I'm not worried about my own scripts, but rather system scripts that require python2. Overnight I realized, though, that these scripts are probably unaffected as they likely state explicitly that they need python 2 by using something like `#!/usr/bin/env python2`, which I think is what you're saying. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

One-liner to get homebrew python working:

zsh

```sh
echo -n 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc
```

bash

```sh
echo -n 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

Explanation:
`>> filename` appends at the end of the file
`source filename` reloads the file

Comment: This worked for me 2017 mpb with 2.9 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7 running macOs 12.6.

Answer (score -1):

I tried a few of the proposed solutions in [How to link home brew python version and set it as default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340871/how-to-link-home-brew-python-version-and-set-it-as-default), but none of them worked.  Ultimately I solved this by symlinking python3 --> python:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```